# Update entities in Orion context-broker

Tags: fiware-orion

How the Orion handles with entity attribute updates?

I have an entity A with three attributes B,C,D.

If I update A with more three attributes X,Y,Z, I need to append in update request B,C,D too? or the Orion will append automatically X,Y,Z in A attribute list ?

Can I update entities without losing old attributes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. APPEND and APPEND_STRICT action types work in that way (the difference is that APPEND does an update if the attribute already exists, while APPEND_STRICT reports and error in that case). The REPLACE action type will replace existing attributes with the ones in the request.

More information on the different action types in [the corresponding section in the Orion user manual](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/develop/user/walkthrough_apiv1/index.html#update-context-elements).